# jython JES: adding a vignette profile

Tags: python, jython, jes

i am trying to create a program in JES with two functions, main() and addVignette(inputPic, vignette)

The main() function is where the two picture objects will be created. I want it to allow the user to select an input picture (the picture to be manipulated) then allow the user to select the vignette (vignette_profile.jpg). Once these two picture objects are created, it should then call addVignette(inputPic, vignette).

The addVignette(inputPic, vignette) function should be written to accept two picture objects as parameters. These picture objects were created in the main() function and passed as input to this function. So basically, using the two picture objects, I need my function to perform the vignette addition operation and this operation should be applied against every pixel within the inputPic picture. The newly edited picture should be displayed to the screen.

I am having trouble multiplying the pictures together. Im not sure if the coding is wrong or my equation is not correct.
i dont know what to code exactly as the vignette profile has darker edges and brighter centre.

thanks guys!

```
    def main():
    file1 = pickAFile()
    file2 = pickAFile()
    inputPic=makePicture(file1)
    vignette=makePicture(file2)
    addVignette(inputPic,vignette)

    def addVignette(inputPic,vignette):
    if getWidth(inputPic)==getWidth(vignette) and getHeight(inputPic)==getHeight(vignette):
    explore(inputPic)
    explore(vignette)
    allpx=getAllPixels(inputPic)
    for px in getAllPixels(inputPic):
    x=getX(px)
    y=getY(px)
    px2=getPixelAt(vignette,x,y)
    x1=getX(px)
    y2=getY(px)
    r1=getRed(px)
    r2=getRed(px2)
    g1=getGreen(px)
    g2=getGreen(px2)
    b1=getBlue(px)
    b2=getBlue(px2)



    if (1<r2<137): 
      r3=(r2-r1)-33
      g3=(g2-g1)+21
      b3=(b1-b2)+51

    if (138<r2<210):
      r3=(r2-r1)-21
      g3=(g2-g1)+49
      b3=(b1-b2)+121

    if (211<r2<246):
      r3=(r2-r1)+66
      g3=(g2-g1)+138
      b3=(b1-b2)+177

    if (247<r2<255):
      r3=(r2-r1)+44
      g3=(g2-g1)+125
      b3=(b2-b1)+201

    setRed(px,r3)
    setGreen(px,g3)
    setBlue(px,b)

  explore(inputPic)  
   else:
   print "Try Again"
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are after but what I got from your question is that you have 2 images that you are trying to merge together, one just happens to be a vignette.

Please replace your `addVignette()` with the below

```
def addVignette(inputPic,vignette):
  # Cycle through each pixel in the input image
  for oPixel in getPixels(inputPic):

    # Get the pixel from the Vignette image that is at the same
    # location as the current pixel of the input image
    vignettePixel = getPixel(vignette, getX(oPixel), getY(oPixel))

    # Get the average of the color values by adding the color
    # values from the input & vignette together and then dividing
    # by 2
    newRed = (getRed(oPixel) + getRed(vignettePixel)) / 2
    newGreen = (getGreen(oPixel) + getGreen(vignettePixel)) / 2
    newBlue = (getBlue(oPixel) + getBlue(vignettePixel)) / 2

    # Make a new color from those values
    newColor = makeColor(newRed, newGreen, newBlue)

    # Assign this new color to the current pixel of the input image
    setColor(oPixel, newColor)

  explore(inputPic)
```

My results with test images below

[image: input image]

[image: Vignette]

[image]